# php echo'ed elements not changing height

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using a php script to read a directory and load all the images into a gallery, inside the `<div id="content">` tag I have a function `<?php create_gallery("path"); ?>` that loads all the images.

The problem is after this the `<div>`'s height is not changed, even though the bodys height is correct and all the images is showing up, the div is not showing up. If it were a transparent div it would be no problem, but it has a background which is only some 83px, from the first span, the height of the div should be some 1000's px height, same height the images are taking up.

php function:

```
  function create_gallery($path){
    $things = scandir($path);
    echo "<span><h1>Artwork Test</h1></span>";
    $imgs = img_arr($path); //only returns images
    for ($i=0; $i<count($imgs); $i++) {
      echo "<div class='art_img_div' onclick='gallery_open_full(this)'><img class='art_img_img' src=" . $imgs[$i] . " /><div class='art_img_div_div'></div></div>";
    }
  }
```

css:

```
#content {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-left: 1px groove rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-right: 1px groove rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  padding: 112px 12px 12px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.art_img_div {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.art_img_img {
  height: 100%;
  flex: none;
}
```

I tried to run a javascript function that recalculated the height of the div based on the `document.body.heightoffSet` with no success as its returning the wrong value.

Comment: `Height` got nothing to do with `PHP`. Share Browser-rendered/parsed HTML with CSS

Comment: what is the css for `art_img_div` and `art_img_img`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a quick project I understood your problem. Correct me if I'm wrong.
The container from #content is not wrapping around the whole images. The problem here is, that you use a

```
float:left
```

on the image container. Cause of that it is taken out of the page flow (and the parent element is not fully wrapped around them). Simple fix is to add a

```
#content:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

You have by the way a padding-bottom at #content which gets immediately overwritten by the padding attribute.
PS: A jsfiddle would help next time :)

Comment: Oh and another by the way, a height: 100%; doesn't do anything unless you haven't explicitly set a fix value (in px) on the parent element.